# MySQL query returning only one row because of SUM function in it

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create an advertisement query where I want to fetch data of all the impressions per advertisement. One user can have multiple advertisements and impressions will be counted in a table on per day basis. So for each day I will have one different row. Here is how my query currently looks like.

```
SELECT  
   eac.id,
   eac.gender,
   eac.start_date,
   eac.end_date,
   eac.ad_image_path,
   eac.ad_link,
   eac.requestfrom,
   eac.traffic,
   eac.registertype,
   eacr.region_id,
   eac.active,
   eac.impression,
   eac.center_image_path,
   eac.bottom_image_path,
   eac.approved_by,
   er.name as country_name,
   eac.budget,
   sum(budget/ (DATEDIFF(end_date,start_date)) *1000) as daily_imp,  
   eaa.impression_count,
   eac.customer_id,
   eaa.created_at
FROM 
   `enrich_advert_customer` eac         
   JOIN `enrich_advert_customer_regions` eacr ON eac.id = eacr.advert_customer_id  
   JOIN `enrich_regions` er ON er.id = eacr.region_id
   LEFT JOIN `enrich_advert_abstract` eaa on eac.id = eaa.advert_customer_id        
WHERE 
   eac.requestfrom ='web' AND
   eac.registertype = 'paid' AND
   eac.active = 1 AND
   eac.approved_by = 1 AND
   eac.gender ='male' AND
   er.name = 'india' AND
   eac.start_date <= '2018-11-5' AND
   eac.end_date >= '2018-11-10'
```

But the problem here is if I am using

```
sum(budget/ (DATEDIFF(end_date,start_date)) *1000) as daily_imp
```

this then its returning only one row at a time.

If you can suggest where I am making a mistake that will be helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: 'If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Simplify the problem, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `group by` clause and others column in there as you applyied aggregation

```
SELECT  eac.id,eac.gender,eac.start_date,eac.end_date,eac.ad_image_path,eac.ad_link,eac.requestfrom,eac.traffic,eac.registertype,eacr.region_id,eac.active,eac.impression,eac.center_image_path,eac.bottom_image_path,eac.approved_by,er.name as country_name,eac.budget,sum(budget/ (DATEDIFF(end_date,start_date)) *1000) as daily_imp  ,eaa.impression_count,eac.customer_id,eaa.created_at

FROM 
    `enrich_advert_customer` eac 

JOIN 
    `enrich_advert_customer_regions` eacr
   ON eac.id = eacr.advert_customer_id 

JOIN 
    `enrich_regions` er
   ON er.id = eacr.region_id

LEFT JOIN 
    `enrich_advert_abstract` eaa
    on eac.id = eaa.advert_customer_id

WHERE eac.requestfrom ='web' AND
      eac.registertype = 'paid' AND
      eac.active = 1 AND
      eac.approved_by = 1 AND
      eac.gender ='male' AND
      er.name = 'india' AND
      eac.start_date <= '2018-11-5' AND
      eac.end_date >= '2018-11-10'
group by eac.id,eac.gender,eac.start_date,eac.end_date,eac.ad_image_path,eac.ad_link,eac.requestfrom,eac.traffic,eac.registertype,eacr.region_id,eac.active,eac.impression,eac.center_image_path,eac.bottom_image_path,eac.approved_by,er.name,eac.budget,  eaa.impression_count,eac.customer_id,eaa.created_at
```

Comment: Still getting one record

Comment: have you checked your where clause - with this conditions how many records are you getting first check that - if your where conditions ok then you should get all records

Comment: Ok yes my date conditions are something problem there.